# Apt-get broken in ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, update-manager

I'm unable to install or update any Ubuntu package or software. When I try to run any command with `apt-get` I'm getting the error below. I have tried following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _ZN11CommandLine10GetCommandEPKNS_8DispatchEjPKPKc

sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt
apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _ZN11CommandLine10GetCommandEPKNS_8DispatchEjPKPKc
```

I have tried the following solution:
Download apt package from [apt package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/amd64/apt/download) and try to install using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 265812 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.0.1ubuntu2.13) over (1.0.1ubuntu2.13) ...
Preparing to unpack libapt-pkg4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21) over 
(0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.9.16); however:
  Version of libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 on system is 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

Even when I try to reinstall Ubuntu it doesn't work.

Comment: Is that all? What command did you use? Can you post all output as is.

Comment: @mikewhatever not only update if i use any apt-get command. it is showing same error

Comment: @mikewhatever i have updated question can you review again ?

Comment: I'm getting suspicious that your system may be left in an inconsistent state after a botched release upgrade. Just to verify that you're truly on Ubuntu 14.04: could you please include the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the manual re-installation of `apt`, but you need to do the same for all packages from the  [`apt` source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/apt) that are also a dependency of the `apt` package, i. e. most importantly [`libapt-pkg4.12`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libapt-pkg4.12/download).

The `dpkg` command will look something like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb
```

After that you should:

1. Check that there are no package repositories from previous releases in the repository list:

   ```
   grep -e '^\s*[^\s#].*trusty' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
   ```

   should have empty output.

   If you want to be perfectly safe, [restore the default](/q/124017/175814).
2. Update the local package index:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Upgrade potentially left-over packages from Precise to their newer version from Trusty:

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

Comment: @david-forester even i tried your suggestion, it doesnt work for me. i update error logs in question

Comment: According to the added listing in your question you didn't choose the right version of `libapt-pkg4.12`. The current version for Trusty is `1.0.1ubuntu2.13`, which is appears in the example command and behind the link in my answer.

Comment: I have installed `libapt-pkg4.12` and `1.0.1ubuntu2.13`. Removed package repositories. While updating ubuntu `apt-get update` I'm getting following error

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion.

Comment: I have solved the way you explained me helped a lot.